# Big file folder icon at the center of the screen when tried macOS high Sierra public beta

Tags: beta-seed-program, high-sierra

Today, the long-waited macOS high Sierra was finally arrived. I  can’t help trying it after downloading it for several hours. But out of my expectation, the updating is stuck during the process of rebooting system. The a big file folder appeared at the center of the dark screen(see attached pictures). It popped out every 2 seconds. Very annoying!

I tried to turn off my MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015) and the problem persisted. How should I do it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try recovery mode?

Comment: Cmd/R or Cmd/opt/R at the boot chimes. I'm guessing the first won't work, or it would have gone to the built-in recovery automatically, if it could find it - so it looks like the 2nd one, Internet Recovery might be your only option.

Comment: It won’t work. I tired both

Comment: Then you need a USB or an external HD/SSD you can boot from, or take it to an Apple Store. Your Time Machine drive ought to be bootable.

Comment: Oh. Understand. Will bring it to the Apple store